# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

Im new to SpringBoot. Please let me know how to fix this below error.

"Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect"

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect.<init>(SQLiteDialect.java:20)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect.registerColumnType(int, java.lang.String)'

The calling method's class, org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/kakarthi/.m2/repository/com/zsoltfabok/sqlite-dialect/1.0/sqlite-dialect-1.0.jar!/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLiteDialect.class

The called method's class, org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/kakarthi/.m2/repository/com/zsoltfabok/sqlite-dialect/1.0/sqlite-dialect-1.0.jar!/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLiteDialect.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect: file:/C:/Users/kakarthi/.m2/repository/com/zsoltfabok/sqlite-dialect/1.0/sqlite-dialect-1.0.jar
    org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect: file:/C:/Users/kakarthi/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.1.6.Final/hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springLearning</groupId>
    <artifactId>springLearning</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springLearning</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zsoltfabok</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.40.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please let me know how to fix this below error.

"Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect".

I have tried removing or increasing verisons but still im facing issue. Any help would be apricated.

Comment: Remove `sqlite-dialect` and `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`. Fix your imports (which now will probably fail as you probably have `javax.persistence` instead `jakarta.persistence`. As the `sqlite-dialect` you are using is from 2017 I doubt it is compatible with the most recent version(s) of Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

From Hibernate 6, SQLite dialect is supported.
We have to import in our pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Copy
And in our application properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you.
You should remove from your pom.xml the **sqlite-dialect** dependency and modify your **hibernate** dependency this way :

the **groupId tag** should contain **org.hibernate.orm**

and your **artifactId** should contain **hibernate-community-dialects**

also in your **application.properties** you should have **spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect**